# Alignment of images and data change in html webpages

Tags: html

Hello every one i had created a website using dreamweaver in windows7 which worked good in my system.I opened the same html site in another system with operating system windows xp and even in windows 7, but all the alignments of images ,textfields ,buttons and header image,content etc everything has been changed.what might be the problem.Can any one help me in solving this problem.Your answer will be most precious thing to me.Thanks to every one whose going to spend time on reading this question.

Comment: Check if your CSS is being downloaded in the browser correctly.

Comment: Your question is too open-ended and will probably be closed. In essence it boils why to "why do things look different across browsers and systems?" and the answer is "because", or more precisely "because not every browser follows the standards and even when they do the standard isn't always specific enough to prevent variations". This is why you need to test your site in a range of browsers AND make sure your code is standards-compliant. If you have a specific problem and code samples then update or ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more details it's hard to properly answer your question. Going to take a shot in the dark about a common issue.

If you did it in Dreamweaver you *probably* used its interface to drag and drop div elements around to place them in exactly the right positions. The problem with this method is that DW will use positioning relative to your screen size and it might not show up too well on other resolutions.

The solution to this is to make sure you code your containers correctly and not have a look at DW's CSS to fix it.

Without the HTML of your page (post it in pastebin and link it here), can't give a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you [VALIDATE](http://validator.w3.org/) your code. In my experience using dreaweaver, the doctype declaration and the order of the tags can affect image positioning.

Answer (score 0):

That was because you used different browser. In using Dreamweaver, try to not leave default values. For better debug you should code it with HTML and CSS. Those are not programming languages because they don't need exactly programming knownledge.

A really good [HTML lessons at w3c](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_intro.asp).
A really good [CSS lessons at w3c](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_intro.asp).